# Typo3: Possible 2 installations on 1 Linux server?

Tags: php, linux, apache, typo3

After double checking the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)'s to be sure this is an alright question here, I've got a perhaps simple question about the CMS Typo3.

The title puts it quite literally, but I'll elaborate what I have, what I'm thinking about doing, and what I'd like to achieve.

What I have is access to a Linux server via the good ol' ssh PuTTy. Newest versions of everything right down the PHP in the Apache installation. I've also already installed one Typo3 on it, via the "Introduction Package".

What I'm thinking about is the fact I've already made some changes (this first installation has been my sandbox to learn in, though it's still quite confusing and all of the documentation is "old").

What I'd like to achieve is simple. I'd like to export a site that is about 80% developed from our partner client and possibly import it to a "new installation" of Typo3, thus leaving the 2 completely in tact.

My question comes before my attempt due to my concern as to how this may affect any Apache or PHP files (such as the ini). I'd like to know if anyone has tried this and/or knows of any possible "cons" in attempting such maneuver.

In a similar area, I've one other question, my Intro Pack does not seem to have an "Import" tab?

I've a lot of other questions, but I'll save them for an expert or possibly other post here on SO.  For now, if anyone has any info on dual installations, I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by setting up separate [Apache virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/), and putting each TYPO3 instance in its own virtual host. [Apache's documentation on how to do that is here.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)

Each virtual host gets its own Web root directory, so you'd put the TYPO3 files for each site in the Web root you specify for its virtual host. Then they'd be accessible via whatever domain you assign to each virtual host.

This will require modifying the Apache configuration, and having sufficient permissions to restart/reload Apache when you're done. Different distros handle setting up different virtual hosts in different ways, but Googling "Apache virtual host" plus the name of your distro should return instructions on how it's done there.

Answer (score 1):

You can run as many Installations of TYPO3 as you wish on your Server; for testing it's absolutely sufficient to give them different subdomains to live in.

You can install the core in the root dir (above public_html) and symlink to it from all your TYPO3 instances. http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2008/06/installing-typo3-with-upgrades-in-mind.html

About the import question: TYPO3's "export/import" functionality is in the pagetree. Right click a page, then -> import t3d.  But it's not very reliable, so you'd be better off to import the entire DB into mySQL. If the TYPO3 version numbers don't correspond, make them correspond first and carefully update TYPO3 afterwards.

The other thing is that you can of course run multiple sites inside one TYPO3 installation, but that's probably not what you're up to.